# Opening a modal from a different div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have two html, A.html and B.html; Is it possible to load/show a modal on A.html in B.html?

Comment: I created a separate Html file to hold the content of the modal and using the jquery.load(), I was able to load the modal into a div on both html.

Answer (score 0):

Are they open on separate pages/browsers, and your question is about how to invoke a function on page 1, and a dialog/modal shows up on page 2?

If this is, you'll need a pub/sub API, most likely with a backend service to handle this.